# How to install SQL Server 2012 on a freshly installed 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-7

Please advise how to install SQL Server 2012 on freshly installed 64-bit Windows 7. I was trying to install, but couldn't do so because of some system error.

1. Do I have to install Visual Studio?
2. Can it run without MS visual Studio?

Below is the error that occurs while installing please advise.

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2012  Setup
>
> The following error has occurred: SQL Server Setup has encountered an error when running a Windows Installer file. Windows Installer error message: The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Windows Installer file: e:\f6022cc40a039c86e714c5717dd648\redist\VisualStudioShell\VC10SP1\vc_red.msi
>
> Windows Installer log file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170722_213946\VC10Redist_Cpu64_1_ComponentUpdate.log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr6PQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual C++ 10.

Comment: why ? what's the reason for Visual C++ 10? Do we have any alternate way? if not then how would i install Visual C++ 10?